# Is it possible to find the vertices of a triangle given its incenter, circumcenter and centroid?

Tags: triangles, triangle-centres

It is well-known that for an equilateral triangle the centroid, incenter and circumcenter are all the same, and that for any non-equilateral triangle these three centers are different points. So, apart from equilateral (degenerate) case, can we find the vertices of a triangle given its centroid, incenter and circumcenter?

It seems to me that the answer is positive, though I couldn't find literature on these question.

Note: The case of isosceles triangles is rather easy, since the incenter lies in the Euler line and the problem can be transformed into a one dimensional equation.

Comment: It does not look so: see https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/index.shtml where the triple (I,O,G) isn't mentionned in the big array ($G$ = centroid).

Comment: [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/O-H-I.shtml) may be relevant (also from cut-the-knot, oddly).  Note that you can find the orthocenter given your data (and conversely) so the problems are equivalent.  To stress, however:  that source is concerned with classical construction (straight edge and compass).  Thus a solution which came down to extracting the root of a cubic or quartic would, generally, be ruled out of bounds.